# how to start sql server agent etl job after complete oracle process

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have Oracle source and SQL Server. every day 12.00 AM Oracle data populate for oracle database tables, after that sql server agent jobs run manually by me after Oracle Data Extraction completed. for SQL Server databases, I want to automate this process. when oracle data population completed i need to run sql server agent jobs automatically, how can i do this.

Comment: How is the Oracle Data Extraction process scheduled and executed? If you don't have an enterprise scheduler to coordinate distributed batch processing, you could execute `sp_startjob` from script at the successful completion of the extract.

Comment: You can either have a SQL job that runs from "X" time to "X" time that checks for a "Completed" value in an oracle table (and runs the Sql jobs if the value is found), or trigger the job via a DBLink Execution on the Oracle Side.  Sorry I just realized this is more or less what @DanGuzman just said.  Apologies Dan.